# Can I use spring boot Thymeleaf with Jsp

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I want to use Thymeleaf and spring security in my spring boot project. But template not exist.
Error message:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Error resolving template "home", template might not exist
>   or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: You can not use JSP by using Thymeleaf library

Comment: So, Can I use spring security without Thymeleaf

Comment: Surely. those are different library and no relation between them

Comment: Can you give me some example, please

Answer (score 0):

For Rendering the jsp in spring boot you can either use Thymeleaf or embeded-tomcat dependencies. Both of them will take care of your view resolver part in spring.